# Different hyperparameter combinations get equal f1 score

Tags: performance, hyperparameters

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IUeh.png)
As shown in the figure, different hyperparameter combinations (max_depth and n_estimators) get exactly equal f1 score.why is that

Different hyperparameters should have different f1 scores.Can anyone help me.Thanks you